# accessing factor components in R

Tags: r

I am trying to access the components of a factor by their index number. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, everytime I access them by their number i get the same first value.

```
oppData <- read.csv("/cloud/project/OppMapping.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
managers <- oppData$Manager <- as.factor(oppData$Manager)
managers[1]
```

When I do `managers[1]` or `managers[2]` I get the same first value displayed. I also tried `nlevels(managers)` and confirmed that the factor has five values.

> [1] Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith 
>   Bob Smith      [7] Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith
>   Bob Smith     Bob Smith     [13] Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith
>   Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     [19] Bob Smith     Bob Smith
>   Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     [25] Bob Smith
>   Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith
>   [31] Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     Bob Smith     George
>   Joseph George Joseph [37] George Joseph George Joseph George Joseph
>   George Joseph George Joseph Derek Abraham [43] Derek Abraham Derek
>   Abraham Derek Abraham John Doe      John Doe      John Doe      [49]
>   John Doe      John Doe      John Doe      John Doe      John Doe
>   John Doe      [55] John Doe      John Doe      John Doe      John Doe 
>   Michael Smith Michael Smith [61] Michael Smith Michael Smith Michael
>   Smith Michael Smith Michael Smith Michael Smith [67] Michael Smith
>   Michael Smith Levels: Bob Smith Derek Abraham George Joseph John Doe
>   Michael Smith

Please advise!

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? We don't have access to your OppMapping data and the following code works as you would like:
l <- as.factor(letters)
l[5]

Comment: I tried with manually creating a factor, it works there, it is just not working with the oppMapping data.

Comment: I have added the output to the original post as well that shows the levels at the bottom.

Comment: You need to create a reproducible example. That could mean giving us a snippet of the data.frame

Comment: @Adam, I was able to figure it out, I did levels(managers)[1] and I was able to get what I was looking for. Thank you!